# Convert TSQL to NoSQL with primary key nodes

Tags: c#, json, firebase, t-sql, nosql

How can the following TSQL Query results be returned as JSON where the primary keys are BoardId, StoreId and Code?

| BoardId | StoreId | Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 070 | 001 | 20011 | 2 |
| 070 | 006 | 20011 | 1 |
| 070 | 001 | 20074 | 67 |
| 070 | 002 | 20074 | 15 |
| 070 | 004 | 20074 | 51 |

The transformation would look like the following, which is using the BoardId, StoreId, Code as path:

```
"70" : {
    "001" : {
      "20011" : {        
          "BoardId" : 70,
          "Code" : "20011",
          "Quantity" : 2,
          "StoreId" : "001",
          "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9300502-04:00"       
      },
      "20074" : {      
          "BoardId" : 70,
          "Code" : "20074",
          "Quantity" : 67,
          "StoreId" : "001",
          "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9797415-04:00"        
      },
      "20163" : {       
          "BoardId" : 70,
          "Code" : "20163",
          "Quantity" : 3,
          "StoreId" : "001",
          "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9807881-04:00"        
      },
      "20611" : {      
          "BoardId" : 70,
          "Code" : "20611",
          "Quantity" : 1,
          "StoreId" : "001",
          "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9807923-04:00"       
      }...
```

Can this be done using a TSQL Query using 'for JSON'? I can't seem to find anything without making something custom to the above example. Open to alternate suggestions. I need to keep some SQL tables in sync with Firebase. This would also allow me to do bulk inserts/updates.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly what you're asking, but I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [reducing data nesting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

The closest equivalent of your SQL data structure in Firebase Realtime Database is:

```
"70_001_20011" : {
  "BoardId" : 70,
  "Code" : "20011",
  "Quantity" : 2,
  "StoreId" : "001",
  "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9300502-04:00"       
},
"70_001_20074" : {
  "BoardId" : 70,
  "Code" : "20074",
  "Quantity" : 67,
  "StoreId" : "001",
  "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9797415-04:00"        
},
"70_001_20163" : {
  "BoardId" : 70,
  "Code" : "20163",
  "Quantity" : 3,
  "StoreId" : "001",
  "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9807881-04:00"        
},
"70_001_20611" : {
  "BoardId" : 70,
  "Code" : "20611",
  "Quantity" : 1,
  "StoreId" : "001",
  "TimeStamp" : "2021-09-20T12:37:18.9807923-04:00"       
}...
```

So here we've combined three values that are your primary key in SQL, into the key for each node in Firebase. With that we then have a flat list of nodes, just like you have a flat list of rows in SQL.

The behavior of the database is still going to be different (and I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for more on why and how that is), but this structure is a decent starting point.

Comment: Great Answer, Thanks! Thanks for the recommendations as well.